# Changing text in Android on text change causes overflow error

Tags: android

I want to create an application that can transform text the user enters in an `EditText` widget in real time, and I've added a `TextWatcher` to allow me to do stuff on text change, but it's causing an overflow error because I'm basically creating an endless loop (`onTextChange -> code to change text -> onTextChange -> etc...`).

Anyone got an idea on how to get around this issue?

**Here's an example**

```
private boolean isEditable = true;
private EditText text;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (isEditable) {
                isEditable = false;
                styleText(s.toString());
            } else {
                isEditable = true;
            }
        }

    });

}

private void styleText(String completeText) {
    text.setText(completeText + " test");
}
```

And while the above actually seems to be working, I cannot get it to work with `Html.fromHtml();`, which is what I intend to use.

**EDITED AGAIN**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText text;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        text.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        text.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        text.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        text.setText("Test!");
    }
}
```

It's throwing a `StackOverflowException` on line 37, which is "`text.setText("Test!");`"

Comment: Maybe set a flag when you're editing to turn your watcher off?

Comment: I've added some code.

@jeffamaphone - I've already done this, and it seems to be working, but not when I set the text using `Html.fromHtml()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

EDIT: And works, no exception is thrown:

```
  txtwt = new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Log.i("REACHES AFTER", "YES");

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                Log.i("REACHES BEFORE", "YES");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                text.removeTextChangedListener(txtwt);//after this line you do the editing code 
                text.setText("TEST");
                Log.i("REACHES ON", "YES");
                text.addTextChangedListener(txtwt); // you register again for listener callbacks

            }};
       text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text.addTextChangedListener(txtwt);
```

This is the Logcat proof, when I dramatically pushed keys :

```
08-28 19:53:21.265: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.276: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.276: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.296: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.305: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.305: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.745: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.755: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.755: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.775: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.785: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:21.785: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:22.698: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:22.705: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:22.705: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:23.855: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:23.865: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:23.865: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.385: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.395: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.395: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.485: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.485: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.485: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.515: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.525: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.525: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.625: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.635: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.635: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.654: INFO/REACHES BEFORE(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.665: INFO/REACHES ON(492): YES
08-28 19:53:24.665: INFO/REACHES AFTER(492): YES
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just seems to be crashing again with the following error `08-28 20:44:42.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3198): java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: I've edit my answer remove the listener in the `afterTextChange`. Actually, you might need to remove the listener based when you edit the text changed. Lets say if you trigger edits in the `afterTextChanged`, there you remove the listener, thus you prevent for infinite loop in the `TextWatcher` methods.

Comment: on which line StackOverflow is thrown?

Comment: It's a line in the code I use to change the text, but all that's doing is setting a new text using `text.setText();`

Comment: Are you sure you have removed the text watcher listener before you do `.setText()`

Comment: Please check the updated question. It wouldn't reach anything after setText().

Comment: See my edited answer. I tested. I often write the answers by heart. This code does not throws anything. The previous answer did throw

Comment: Errr... For some reason, it doesn't like `Html.fromHtml("<b>a test string</b>");` and crashes :-( Regular text strings work just fine, but it doesn't like Spannable ones.

Comment: Omg, I am so sorry. I accidentally missed something. Thanks, it works without any problems.

Comment: Hmm... try `Html.fromHtml("<b>a test string</b>").toString()` or make your own `Spannable` with pure java.

Comment: i used this solution in afterTextChanged

Answer (score 6):

```
private String originalValue;
void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
   if (text.toString().equals(originalValue)) {
      // do nothing
   } else {
      //change your text
      originalValue = text.toString();
   }
}
```

Edited:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       String currentText = s.toString();
       if (currentText.equals(originalValue)) { //the originalValue must be defined outside of the Watcher
          originalValue = styleText(currentText);
          // text.setText(originalValue); //if styleText doesn't do this
       } else {
          return;
       }
}
```