# Android: why i am not able to change the value of EditText with respect to another EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textchanged

I am going to change the text of the edittext based on the value enter on the another edittext. and also like same thig with visa-versa.

For that i have use the TextChanged Listener and implemented as like below:

```
 includedText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(!(includedText.getText().toString().equals("")))
                {
                    double included = Double.parseDouble(includedText.getText().toString());
                    included = roundTwoDecimals(included);

                    String amt = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(included-(included/1.15)));
                    String excluded = String.valueOf(included/1.15);
                    System.out.println("The Amount is: "+amt);
                    amountText.setText(amt);
                    excludedText.setText(excluded); //////// Error Line
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });


    // worked
    excludedText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!(excludedText.getText().toString().equals("")))
            {
                double excluded = Double.parseDouble(excludedText.getText().toString());
                excluded = roundTwoDecimals(excluded);

                String amt = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(excluded*0.15));
                String included = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(excluded+(excluded*0.15)));
                System.out.println("The Amount is: "+amt);
                amountText.setText(amt);
                includedText.setText(included);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

But after doing this i am not able to get the text change. for Secod EditText its worked nice but while i use the First EditText then it gives me error at the commented line.

Error Log:

```
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077): java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:69)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:102)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:131)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:261)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:150)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:4851)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5348)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2688)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:93)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.afterTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:74)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6145)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2695)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:93)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.afterTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:74)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6145)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2695)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:93)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.afterTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:74)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6145)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2695)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:93)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.afterTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:74)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6145)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2695)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:93)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
12-22 13:08:17.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTAct
```

So whats the wrong with this ? Why i am not able to get effect for both the EditText ?
Thanks.

Comment: can you please post the error message. ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this is because you are doing **setText**() inside  **onTextChanged** . So when you change the text onTextChanged will be called and again inside onTextChanged you are calling **setText**(). So thr text changed again and **onTextChanged**() will be called again and this process will continue till stack overflow and result to stackOverFlow error. Hope you can understand...

user  **removeTextChangedListener()** before **setText(**).

***Edit:***

Define
`TextWatcher excludeTW,includeTW;` //globaly.

```
    includedText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.include);
    excludedText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.exclude);

    includeTW = new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
             if(!(includedText.getText().toString().equals("")))
                {
                    excludedText.removeTextChangedListener(excludeTW);
                    String included = includedText.getText().toString();
                    excludedText.setText(included); //////// Error Line
                }

        }



    };


    excludeTW = new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        includedText.removeTextChangedListener(includeTW);
        String excluded = excludedText.getText().toString();
        includedText.setText(excluded);

        }



    };
    includedText.addTextChangedListener(includeTW) ;
    excludedText.addTextChangedListener(excludeTW);
```

Comment: Still i am not gettig the answer. Please will you help me in this?

Comment: @Sujit: Don't understand, I followed the same example as above. But addTextChangeListener works for one Edittext but does not works for the other. Here is the original link to where I have asked the problem about it in detail [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917419/addtextchangedlistener-works-for-one-edittext-but-not-for-the-other) Could you please look into this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is causing you problem because you are putting the whole code in recursion. i.e 1st editext changes the text of 2nd edittext which again changes the text of 1st edittext...this goes on forever..

Solution: apply some logic that adds the text change listener when the 1st edit text has lost its focus n vice versa.

Comment if u need help.

```
setOnTextChangeListener(true);

    excludedTextWatch = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (!(excludedText.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                double excluded = Double.parseDouble(excludedText.getText()
                        .toString());
                excluded = roundTwoDecimals(excluded);

                String amt = String
                        .valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(excluded * 0.15));
                String included = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(excluded
                        + (excluded * 0.15)));
                System.out.println("The Amount is: " + amt);
                includedText.setText("" + included);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };

    includedTextWatch = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            if (!(includedText.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                double included = Double.parseDouble(includedText.getText()
                        .toString());
                included = roundTwoDecimals(included);

                String amt = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(included
                        - (included / 1.15)));
                String excluded = String.valueOf(included / 1.15);
                System.out.println("The Amount is: " + amt);
                excludedText.setText("" + excluded); // ////// Error
                                                        // Line
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };

    includedText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            excludedText.removeTextChangedListener(excludedTextWatch);
            includedText.removeTextChangedListener(includedTextWatch);
            setOnTextChangeListener(hasFocus);
        }
    });
}

private void setOnTextChangeListener(boolean shouldSetTheListener) {
    if (shouldSetTheListener) {
        includedText.addTextChangedListener(includedTextWatch);
    } else {
        excludedText.addTextChangedListener(excludedTextWatch);
    }
}
```

This will definately work.

Comment: What is includedTextWatch and excludedTextWatch ??

Comment: Your answer gives me nullPointerException at the line i have comented in the question.

Comment: it will because you need to initialize the edit text before u use them. and the includedTextWatch are variables that will be used, instead of anonymous inner class. So tht we can remove them when not needed.

Comment: I have initialize the EditText as like this   amountText.setText(""); // TextView
     excludedEditText.setText(""); // EditText
     includedEditText.setText(""); // EditText

Comment: But still while i am going to change the Value of editTExt it gives me error.

Comment: Don't you even known to initialize a view object. its done by findviewbyId method not by setting the text to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have hooked up an infinite recursion with both the edit text.

onTextChanged() of `includedText` calls `excludedText.setText()` which triggers the onTextChanged on `excludedText` which again calls `includedText.setText()`. And this repeats on forever until it crashes.

Hence the Stackoverflow. [See here for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222944/changing-text-in-android-on-text-change-causes-overflow-error)

Edit: I haven't compiled it, just edited it as is. See [here](http://codepad.org/VDukREJf)

Comment: So what shoould i have to change do To make it effet and works as i have said ?

Comment: Please help me in My condition.

Comment: Thanks st0le for answer. and i have just solve the Question with Sujit answer. But thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer, Actually you didn't...Try editing the edittext a second time, it wont work, the Next time. If you see my code, you have to add the textwatcher again....

Answer (score 0):

below code will work 100 percent try it declare globaly TextWatcher t1,t2;

```
         final EditText myOutputBox = (EditText) ConvertView1.findViewById(R.id.editTextbackrate);

           myOutputBox.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

           final EditText myOutputBox1 = (EditText) ConvertView1.findViewById(R.id.edittextlayrate);

           myOutputBox.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

           myOutputBox1.addTextChangedListener(t1 = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                   if(s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                   {
                       myOutputBox.setText("");
                  }
                   else
                   {

                           myOutputBox.removeTextChangedListener(t2);

                           String x = myOutputBox1.getText().toString();
                           myOutputBox.setText(x);

                               }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                myOutputBox.addTextChangedListener(t2 = new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                               if(s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                               {
                                    Log.i("t2", "1");
                                   myOutputBox1.removeTextChangedListener(t1);
                                   myOutputBox1.setText("");

                               }
                               else
                               {




                                       myOutputBox1.removeTextChangedListener(t1);
                                       String x = myOutputBox.getText().toString();
                                       myOutputBox1.setText(x);


                                           }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                }); 


            }
        });
```