# addTextChangedListener works for one EditText but not for the other

Tags: android, addtextchangedlistener

I am asking this question after going through every possible way of resolving it.

I have two EditText defined as follows

```
private EditText firstText;
private EditText secondText;
```

I am resetting the value of one EditText on change of the other and vice versa. 
I was getting a stackOverFlow error because of the very same reason of calling EditText recursively.

Hence, I followed [this link to solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600587/android-why-i-am-not-able-to-change-the-value-of-edittext-with-respect-to-anoth)

Luckily, things work but only for secondText not for the firstText. This means when I change value for secondText, I see updated value in firstText. But same does not go for firstText.

When I tried debugging by printing a garbbish value I got to know that firstText is not calling on addTextChangedListener.

Here is the code for both of my EditText

```
 firstTextTW = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("I am inside firstTextTW");
            int afterCount = firstText.getText().length();
            System.out.println(afterCount);
            if(afterCount == 1) {
                //if the character is null then do nothing

            }else{
                System.out.println("Inside firstTextTw");//debugging by printing
                Double number = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                String SetCurrency = actv.getText().toString();
                String SecondCurrency = actv2.getText().toString();

                SetCurrency = SetCurrency.trim();
                SecondCurrency = SecondCurrency.trim();

                SecondTask task = new SecondTask();
                try {
                    double CurrencyDiff;
                    CurrencyDiff = Double.parseDouble(task.execute("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=" + SetCurrency + "&symbols=" + SetCurrency + "," + SecondCurrency).get());

                    Double final_result = number * CurrencyDiff;
                    Double final_value = Math.round(final_result * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
                    secondText.removeTextChangedListener(secondTextTW);
                    secondText.setText(final_value.toString());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

    secondTextTW = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Double number_to_be_divided_from = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
            String auto1 = actv.getText().toString();
            String auto2 = actv2.getText().toString();

            auto1 = auto1.trim();
            auto2 = auto2.trim();

            SecondTask task = new SecondTask();
            Double currency_converter;

            try {
                currency_converter = Double.parseDouble(task.execute("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=" + auto1 + "&symbols=" + auto1 + "," + auto2).get());
                System.out.println(currency_converter);
                Double resultToUpdate = number_to_be_divided_from / currency_converter;
                Double resultToUpdateFinal = Math.round(resultToUpdate * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
                //System.out.println(resultToUpdateFinal);
                firstText.removeTextChangedListener(firstTextTW);
                firstText.setText(resultToUpdateFinal.toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

    firstText.addTextChangedListener(firstTextTW) ;
    secondText.addTextChangedListener(secondTextTW);
```

As one can see I am calling addTextChangedListener on both the EditText and I have even defined firstTextTW and secondTextTW properly as global variables just below the two EditText

Thanks in advance

**Edit- code for setOntouchListener used for num keypad**

```
firstText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "9"));
                    }
                });

                eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "8"));
                    }
                });

                seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "7"));
                    }
                });

                six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "6"));
                    }
                });

                five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "5"));
                    }
                });

                four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "4"));
                    }
                });

                three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "3"));
                    }
                });

                two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "2"));
                    }
                });

                one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "1"));
                    }
                });

                zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int text_count = firstText.getText().length();
                        if(text_count == 1) {
                        }else{
                            firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "0"));
                        }
                    }
                });


                dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        firstText.setText(firstText.getText().insert(firstText.getText().length(), "."));
                    }
                });

                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int count = firstText.getText().length();
                        if(count==1)
                        {
                            firstText.setText(" ");
                            System.out.println("Replace text with blank space");
                        }
                        else {
                            firstText.setText(firstText.getText().delete(firstText.getText().length() - 1, firstText.getText().length()));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: my guess is you have done a findviewbyid for firstText with the id of secondText

Comment: @VinayWadhwa: no your guess is wrong! Also, I saw that during the loading of app. I make a server call to fetch and set some values for both the textbox. During that time, when asynctask is going on in background. My firstText add change listener works perfectly fine. But once the data is loaded it stops working

Comment: that code would help

Comment: @VinayWadhwa: should I upload the full code

Comment: just the part where firstText is involved would do

Comment: There is setOntouchlistener for numeric keypad. Have uploaded that code as well @VinayWadhwa

Comment: returning false from the onTouchListener might fix your problem.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa: nope it did not work. Should I mail you my whole mainactivity file?

Answer (score 0):

You do as like

```
    mSearchbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
            ivCancelSearch.setVisibility(mSearchbox.getText().length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

similer for other remember get correct id of edittext