# how to make android edittext show a pattern while text is being inserted?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-edittext, hint

I am developing an Android application in which, the user has to input an answer to an edittext view. In order to make things simpler I want the edit text to keep showing the rest of the edittext hint.
For example, if the correct answer is: "Big joe". I generate the following hint:"--- ---" which is 3 dashes then a space and then 3 more dashes . Setting it as a hint is no problem, however, as soon as the user presses on the edittext view the hint vanishes. I want it to stay put and get runned over by the user input. Continuing the example, id user only entered (Wrongly) "Ji" (but wasn't yet done!) then I want the edittext view to contain the text:"Ji- ---". and not just "Ji" as it regulerly would. The hint should stay like a "shdow text" or like "Sit fillers", so as soon as the "sit" is filled it disapears.
So for correct answer what would happen would be the folowing with # marking the cursor:
begin: #-- ---
1st: B#- ---
2nd: Bi# ---
3rd: Big #--
4th: Big j#-
5th: Big jo#
6th: Big joe#. at which point I am not so sure there is even a reason to enable the user to enter more letters.

Answer (score 0):

First set the dashes using `.setText()` instead setting hint. To your `EditText` instance add `TextWatcher` by using `.addTextChangedListener()`. Override the `TextWatcher` methods and use them to manipulate the `EditText` as user types.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html
See `Selection` class
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html

Comment: I have tried that, but did not succeed. It says "It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback" on both beforeTextChanged and onTextChanged where as in afterTextChanged it puts the whole thing into an infinite loop. Is there an example I could follow somewhere?

Comment: in afterTextChanged method remove the listener, change the text re-add the listener again. This works, please find this in one of my answers about stackoverflow exception when you do infinite changes in text.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reach my laptop last night to link you, here it is the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222944/changing-text-in-android-on-text-change-causes-overflow-error

Comment: I've tried, for hours. Best case scenario is that I get thing dubbled in a strange way. For example, if I put for -- -- and I enter a character (for example h), then it puts on h- -- which is good, but if I put another sign it all gets messed up. for example if I anter an i or a second h, instead of getting hi --, I get hhi--. I can't seen to see the reason why. I can't believe there is no simple solution to what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Nikola, I have searched and found the post you gave the link for and got stuck where I just explained in the above comment.

Comment: Yep, you are moving forward. You need to improve the logic. Try saving the existing *correct* entered letters.